# System folders (Downloads, etc.) with blank names

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, user-folders, system-file

For some reason I have duplicates of my "Downloads", "Documents" and other system folders in "This PC" that have blank names and are inusable. Clicking on them does nothing and if I choose "Properties" from their right-click context menus this is the result:

[image: this is the result]

and

[image: Screenshot]

There are no duplicate values in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` key.

I.e. there is only one value for the "Downloads" folder.

EDIT:

My problem is I wish to remove these folders with blank names.

EDIT:

Adding registry key info as per request:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{0AC0837C-BBF8-452A-850D-79D08E667CA7}]
"Name"="MyComputerFolder"
"Category"=dword:00000001
"ParsingName"="::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try to select in Properties the names of these folders - what do they look like (containing strange characters etc)? Try to select the names with the cursor. Do these folders appear when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc, you can see on the properties screenshot there are no names, yes they do appear in Safe mode

Comment: A folder cannot have no name, but it can contain characters that have no visual glyph. Can you click one folder and then press F2 to rename? Does right-click give the option of Delete (don't delete before ensuring backups and then running `chkdsk`)?

Comment: @harrymc, the Downloads, etc. "folders" are special folders that can't be renamed or deleted from the File Explorer.

Comment: You mean that these blank folders behave like special folders and can't be renamed? Why do you think that these are duplicates? What did `chkdsk` say? Check the registry at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions` (see [link](https://winaero.com/windows-11-remove-folders-from-this-pc/)).

Comment: @harrymc, because they appear in the same place as the special "Documents", "Downloads" and etc. "folders"? Because they have teh same icons? Have you seen the screenshot? No, that link is erroneous, I don't have the guid for "Downloads" in that key.

Comment: Lost track of this thread...Are you still trying to solve???

Comment: @KeithMiller, yup. Nothing new after my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Folders are added to `This PC` via one of thwo registry keys:

- Machine-Wide

  - `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\Namespace`
- Per-User (normally empty or non-existent)

  - `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\Namespace`

Under the `HKLM\...\MyComputer\Namespace` key, the default subkeys are:

```
DelegateFolders
{088e3905-0323-4b02-9826-5d99428e115f}
{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}
{1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}
{24ad3ad4-a569-4530-98e1-ab02f9417aa8}
{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}
{3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA}
{3dfdf296-dbec-4fb4-81d1-6a3438bcf4de}
{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}
{A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0}
{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}
{d3162b92-9365-467a-956b-92703aca08af}
{f86fa3ab-70d2-4fc7-9c99-fcbf05467f3a}
```

If those exist and there are no other subkeys, it's most likely an issue with the `ThisPCPolicy` value found under:

- `HKLM\...\FolderDescriptions\<FolderDescriptionID>\PropertyBag`
  The values should be set as follows:

```
FolderDescriptionsID                   Name                ThisPCPolicy
--------------------                   ----                ------------
{0ddd015d-b06c-45d5-8c4c-f59713854639} Local Pictures      Show        
{18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC} My Video            Hide        
{33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB} My Pictures         Hide        
{35286a68-3c57-41a1-bbb1-0eae73d76c95} Local Videos        Show        
{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B} Downloads           Hide        
{4BD8D571-6D19-48D3-BE97-422220080E43} My Music            Hide        
{754AC886-DF64-4CBA-86B5-F7FBF4FBCEF5} ThisPCDesktopFolder Hide        
{7d83ee9b-2244-4e70-b1f5-5393042af1e4} Local Downloads     Show        
{a0c69a99-21c8-4671-8703-7934162fcf1d} Local Music         Show        
{f42ee2d3-909f-4907-8871-4c22fc0bf756} Local Documents     Show        
{FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7} Personal            Hide
```

You can generate a list like above to check your values by copying & pasting the following code block into a **PowerShell** console window and executing:

```
$FDPath   = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions'
$ThisPCID = '{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}'

gci $FDPath | gp |
 ? ParsingName -like "*$ThisPCID\*" |
  select @{ N='FolderDescriptionID' ; E={$_.PSChildName} },
         Name,
         @{ N='ThisPCPolicy' ; E={(gp "$($_.PSPath)\PropertyBag").ThisPCPolicy } } |
Sort FolderDescriptionID
```

Comment: I do get a different output than yours but also my PCID is different and I am using a value that I'm *guessing* is my PC ID, but could you tell me how to get it for certain?

Comment: Are you talking about `{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`, that's a value that's the same for all windows machines --- it doesn't vary by user...

Comment: Huh... well when I run your script the output is nothing but if I remove the "ThisPCID" filter I get a lot of results but with a different GUID at the start.

Comment: Did you use any tweaker programs before this? Does the following registry key exist on your machine? `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{0AC0837C-BBF8-452A-850D-79D08E667CA7}`? If so, export it and edit your question to include the contents of the exported `.reg` file.

Comment: No tweaker program used, the problem started after reinstalling Windows a long time ago, sorry I realise I should've mentioned that earlier. Question edited.